# Create script to drop several tables (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a script that detect and drop the public tables in my posgresql database...

The request I build is the following :

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', table_schema,'.',table_name,';') AS stmt FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_catalog='capsana'
```

Here is a screenshot of the output I got

[image]

I want now to execute the commands (in the stmt column) in an automatic way .. without doing copy paste !

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql to do this;

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    drop_stmt text;
BEGIN
    FOR drop_stmt IN 
    SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', table_schema,'.',table_name) AS stmt 
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_catalog='capsana' LOOP
        EXECUTE drop_stmt;
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Comment: when I execute this command it says : 

ERROR:  loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables
LINE 8:     FOR i IN 
                ^

********** Erreur **********

Comment: yes same error... in fact it indicates error on "i" (in the line FOR i IN), :(

Comment: Should i be declared somewhere ? because it is like it should be declared !

Comment: Oh yes, I added : DECLARE   i text; and it passes .. however it do not execute i.stmt ... it says : ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "i"
LINE 1: SELECT i.stmt

Comment: So gooood , thank you :) so the issue in the first script was "i.stmt" should be "i" instead :)